# Preseed late_command

Tags: preseed, debian-installer, last-command

I am trying to add a `late_command` to my preseed file but I always get errors.

This is the command I am trying to use:

```
in-target curl -L -o /home/$username/postinstall.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/netson/ubuntu-unattended/master/postinstall.sh; \
in-target chmod +x /home/$username/postinstall.sh; \
in-target /bin/sh /home/$username/postinstall.sh;
```

The error I get:

```
Execution of preseed command "in-target curl -L -o /home/$username/postinstall.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/netson/ubuntu-unattended/master/postinstall.sh; \
in-target chmod +x /home/$username/postinstall.sh; \
in-target /bin/sh /home/$username/postinstall.sh;" failed with exit code 127.
```

Comment: When I go to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/netson/ubuntu-unattended/master/postinstall.sh, I get a 404 error

Comment: Indeed there is no `postinstall.sh` in that repository. I suggest that you have a good look at the README of the [repository that you are trying to use](https://github.com/netson/ubuntu-unattended).

Comment: If you dig a bit in the code given there, [this is the seed file that gets dowloaded](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/netson/ubuntu-unattended/master/netson.seed)

Comment: @cleary ah crap. Copy / paste error -- that will be the issue. This is a fork of https://github.com/netson/ubuntu-unattended and the URL should be https://github.com/atwright147/ubuntu-unattended...

Answer (score 2):

I leave you a fully functional `late_command`, you can see the syntax of this:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string cp /cdrom/files/run.sh /target/root/; chmod +x /target/root/run.sh; in-target /bin/bash /root/run.sh; cp /cdrom/files/configs.sh /target/root/;
```